# How are "special" dragons treated in races?

Tags: dragonvale

Dragonvale allows "special" dragons such as epics (Sun, Rainbow) and gem (Emerald, Ruby) to participate in races.  Since it has been established that certain elements are needed to have the best chances in each race, how are "special" dragons treated?  Are they "non-elemental" or "all-elements" or something else?

On a somewhat related note, what causes your "opponent" dragons to be special?  Sometimes I'll enter a special and get all special opponents, other times I get all "normal" dragons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special dragons like rainbow and sun are sort of treated differently. They are non-elemental in a way. When you race, all the other dragons that race are "special" dragons, too. The type of race you race in (Ulster Meadows, Shimmering Fautline, etc.) doesn't matter; it is the boosting skills and luck. If you have great boosting skills (when you tap the line to boost), you will definitely get good rankings. Sometimes it's just plain ol' luck. You can use great boosting, but still end up in 5th place. If you are getting normal dragons when you race with a "rare" dragon, something must be wrong. That shouldn't be happening, it's unnatural. Unless you are racing with a normal dragon, you shouldn't get normal dragons as opponents. Perhaps  it is a glitch. But the main idea here is that when you race with an "epic" dragon or any special dragon, it is not the racing theme that matters, it is the luck and boosting skills.

'

Comment: A long time ago when I asked this, I think it was possible to get elemental dragons racing against non-elemental ones, but I believe that has since changed.  I rarely race any more since I have Kairos, but when I've tried it with Epic I've found it to be super hard - almost rigged for me to lose.  I've decided it isn't worth it, but thank you for the great answer.