# Opposite elements in races

Tags: dragonvale

Each racetrack has two or more elements. If the racing dragon matches the track's element, it'll have a sight advantage.

Is there a disadvantage if the dragon is of the *opposite* element from the track element? For example, if I use a Blazing Dragon (air, fire) on the Cherry Road track (plant, earth, fire), it will have an advantage on the fire parts, be neutral on the plant parts, but will it be neutral or have a disadvantage on the earth parts, since air is the opposite of earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat related question is [what happens when your dragon doesn't have an element](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80301/how-are-special-dragons-treated-in-races) (ie the epics and gem dragons)?  The short answer, or the best answer I can give is: **it doesn't really matter**.  In every race, there will typically be one competitor who is ideal for the track.  If your dragon is non-ideal, but has one or more of the track elements, in my experience you will typically come in second place if you make a more than half-hearted attempt.  In order to consistently beat the ideal competitor, you need an ideal dragon.  You will get slowed down in the non-ideal sections, and whether that penalty is larger for opposite zones is hard to tell, but like I said - it doesn't much matter.

I'll also point out that the Panlong on Year of the Dragon seems to move fast in the Earth and Air zones, so at least in the case of opposite hybrids, the net effect seems to be speed boost.